# Internet Explorer not offering to save credentials for login page

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a login page which I think is fairly straightforward. However, I recently discovered that IE will not offer to save the password (works in Chrome and Firefox though). It doesn't seem to be a problem with settings in IE since several people have reported the problem.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="username">Brugernavn</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" length="20" tabindex=1>
    </p>
<p>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" length="20" tabindex=2>
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log ind" id="submitbutton">
<a href="#" id="forgotpassword" onClick="showForgotPasswordDialog();">Glemt password?</a>
<br/>
</form>
```

The rest of the page should be valid HTML5.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you sure you don't already have a saved password for that url in IE (if you are testing on, localhost or something)

Comment: @pete several people have reported the issue. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer looks for an `<input>` tag in in your form. I'm not sure but maybe the `<p>` & the `<a>` Tags are giving him problems. Try it this way:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <label for="username">Brugernavn</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" length="20" tabindex=1>
  <br>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" length="20" tabindex=2>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log ind" id="submitbutton">
</form>
<a href="#" id="forgotpassword" onClick="showForgotPasswordDialog();">Glemt password?      </a>
```

If it didn't help try this links, maybe you find a solution here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/11/troubleshooting-stored-login-problems-in-ie.aspx

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: w3schools is a terrible resource - see http://w3fools.com . I recommend MDN. Anyways, I hope the BRs are not neccessary.

Comment: I've looked at the w3fools.com site and must say that the text at their bottom gave me a headache: "Spread this message. If you spot someone using or referencing w3schools.com on blog comments, stackoverflow , etc... Send them our way" - how is this  message helping the users?? Normally every developer knows that w3schools doesn't have anything to do with the W3C. MDN is not the salvation but good though :-)

Comment: I tried removing the <p>-tags and moving the <a> tag outside the form, but it didn't work.